# Given intergers n,d,i is [ n*d + (i-d) ]%n equivalent to [n + (i-d)]%n? (% c++ modulo)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

```
Given range of n :[0, 10^5]
..........range of d :[1,n]
..........range of i :[0,n]
```

With the parameters above and their given ranges.
I assumed that (n*d + i-d )%n is equivalent to (n + i-d )%n.
Considering a function that performs d left rotations on an n element(s) array/vector and returns an array/vector containing the rotated output of the input array/vector.

This c++ function below works correctly and yields the correct answer.

```
vector<int> rotLeft_1(vector<int> a, int d) 
{
    int n = a.size();
    vector<int> ans(n,0);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        answer[(n + i-d)%n] = a[i];
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This c++ function below does not work properly for large values of n and d. ie. n = 73642 and d =60581.
As in, the function below sometimes produces a segmentation fault error.

```
vector<int> rotLeft_2(vector<int> a, int d) 
{
    int n = a.size();
    vector<int> ans(n,0);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        answer[(n*d + i-d)%n] = a[i];
    }
    return answer;
}
```

The question now becomes, is my assumption that  (n*d + i-d )%n is equivalent to (n + i-d )%n wrong?
Or is there is more at play here? Thanks alot.

Comment: The two expressions have different overflow conditions. In particular `73642 * 60581 > 2^32` won't fit into a 32-bit integer.

Comment: *Given range of n :[0, 10^5]* -- I bet that this solution doesn't require looping `n` times.  Questions involving rotations require some math, and minimal, if any loops are required.

Comment: Tip for the future: *"does not work properly for large values"* -- a strong indicator that something overflowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With n*d you overflow [INT_MAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits?view=msvc-160).

> Maximum value for a variable of type int. 2147483647

So your n*d value becomes negative as a result of overflow and then you try to access a negative index of the array that cause the segfault.

Solution: I dont see the point to have n*d if you use modulo n right after so you can avoid the multiplication by d.

Also n will not exceed 100000 as stated.